# How to keep radio button checked after clicking search button

Tags: javascript, html

First the radio button is clicked and then the **Submit**; but when page reloads the radio button selection is gone. How to keep radio button checked?

HTML code:

```html
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="reportfrom" id="reportfrom1" value="ucgw">
        <label class="form-check-label" for="reportfromucgw1">UCGW1</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="reportfrom" id="reportfrom2" value="ucgw2">
        <label class="form-check-label" for="reportfromucgw2">UCGW2</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="reportfrom" id="reportfrom3" value="sip01">
        <label class="form-check-label" for="reportfromsip01">SIP01</label>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-info" value="Hentam!" onclick="test()"/> 
</div>
```

JavaScript code:

```js
<script>
    switch(reportfrom)
        {
        case "ucgw":
            var yesBtn = document.getElementById('reportfrom1');
            // Set radio button to checked
            yesBtn.checked = true;
        break;

        case "ucgw2":
            var yesBtn = document.getElementById('reportfrom2');
        // Set radio button to checked
        yesBtn.checked = true;
        break;

        case "sip01":
            var yesBtn = document.getElementById('reportfrom2');
            // Set radio button to checked
            yesBtn.checked = true;
        }
</script>
```

Comment: You need to somehow save the clicked state of the button. Then you can set the button as clicked when the page reloads. Read up on Local Storage in JavaScript.

Comment: i've got it, tq so much for the idea!